# Why doesn't this character conversion work?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, character-encoding

Visual Studio 2008

Project compiled as multibyte character set

```
LPWSTR lpName[1] = {(WCHAR*)_T("Setup")};
```

After this conversion, `lpName[0]` contains garbage (at least when previewed in VS)

`LPWSTR` is typedef'd as follows:
`typedef __nullterminated WCHAR *NWPSTR, *LPWSTR, *PWSTR;`

Comment: If you're compiling for `_MBCS`, then `_T` is not wide. You probably want `L"string goes here"`, and then you won't need the `(WCHAR*)` cast.

Comment: Oh I see the question. It does not work because it is not a craracter conversion. It is a pointer cast. Character conversions are done with character conversion functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an expanded version of my comment above.

The code shown casts a pointer of type A to a pointer of type B. This is a low-vevel, machine-dependent operation. It almost never works as a conversion of an object of type A to an object of type B, **especially** if one type is a regular character type and the other is wide characters.

Imagine that you take a French book, and read it aloud as if it was written in English.

```
FRENCH* book;
readaloud ((ENGLISH*) book);
```

You will mostly hear gibberish. The letters used in the two languages are the same (or similar, at any rate), but the rules of the two languages are are totally different. The representation is the same for both languages, but the meaning is not.

This is very similar to what we have here. Whatever type you have, bits and bytes are the same, but the rules are totally different. You take bits laid out according to regular character rules, and try to interpret them according to wide character rules. It doesn't work. The representation is the same in both cases, but the meaning is not.

To convert one character flavor to another, you in general need a lookup table or some other means to convert each character from one type to the other — change representation, but keep the meaning. Likewise,  to convert a French book into an English book, you need to use a big lookup table a.k.a. dictionary... well, the analogy breaks here, because there's no formal set of conversion rules, you need to be creative! But you get the idea.

The rules of C++ actually prohibit such casts. You can only cast an object type poiner to `void*`, and only use the result to cast it back to the original object type. Everything else is a no-no (unless you are willing to venture in the realm of undefined behavior).

So what should you do?

1. Pick one character variant and stick to it.
2. If you must convert between flavors, do so with a library function.
3. Try to avoid pointer casts, they almost always signal trouble.

Comment: Thank you for a most cogent explanation - Andrew S.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is

```
LPTSTR lpName[1] = {_T("Setup")};
```

The various typedefs with a `T` in them (e.g. `TSTR`, `LPTSTR`) are dependant on whether you use unicode or multi-byte or whatever else. By using these, you should be able to write code that work in whatever encoding you are using (i.e., tomorrow you could switch to ascii, and a large portion of your code should still work).

### Edit

If you are in situation where you really must convert between encodings, then there are various conversion functions available, such as [wcstombs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/wcstombs/) (or [microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) and [mbstowcs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/mbstowcs/). These are defined in `<cstdlib>`

Comment: I'd suggest the ATL(/MFC) conversion helpers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(v=vs.80).aspx